# Do not overwrite settings file, when installing an update with Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have created an Inno Setup script for a C++ app. The script works fine and consists of the following:

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\john\Desktop\My_App_setup\my_app.exe"; \
    DestDir: "{app}"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\john\Desktop\My_App_setup\settings\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\settings"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

The files are the C++ executable `my_app.exe` and a settings text file that is customized by the end user.

What I'd like to do is when I have an new version of `my_app.exe` to update just this file and leave the same settings that the user may have changed so far.

What should I try?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add [`onlyifdoesntexist` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist):

```
Source: "C:\Users\john\Desktop\My_App_setup\settings\*"; \
    DestDir: "{app}\settings"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs onlyifdoesntexist
```