# InnoSetup : Problem with file check function

Tags: inno-setup

I try to make a setup wizard with InnoSetup software to deploy easily my program but I encounter currently a problem with my script.
I am used to make basic setup wizard but now I have to implement a new functionality whose :
*I want to check if a file exist on the computer to not overwrite it.*
I made like this *(in the [files] section)*:

```
[Files]
Source: "{#MyAppExeFile}"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "{#MyAppSrcFolder}*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "{#MyAppSrcFolder}FileFolder\testFile.py"; DestDir: "D:\Users\{username}\myFolderTest\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;Check: needInstallFile(ExpandConstant('{username}'))
```

And i added this following [code] section:

```
[code]
function needInstallFile(user : string) : Boolean;
begin
  if IsTaskSelected('initFile') then begin
    if FileExists('D:\Users\' + user + '\myFolderTest\testFile.py') then begin  
      MsgBox('The file already exist', mbInformation, MB_OK);
      Result:=False;
      exit;
    end else begin
      Result:=True;
      exit;
    end;
   end;
end;
```

When i compile my code, it's work but if the file already exist, i have **three popup** (and not just one like i would want to have). I DON'T understand despite my researches on Internet.

If you have a lead to help me, I'm interested because i'm stuck.

Thank you in advance for your help.
**PS :** *Sorry for my English, i am unfortunatly a french guy.*

Thomas

Comment: Why don't you use the `onlyifdoesntexist` flag?

Comment: I agree with @Oliver, see [Inno Setup: Do not overwrite settings file, when installing an update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45480309/850848).

Comment: To answer your literal question, see [''Check' function is executing multiple times in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46037128/850848).

Comment: @Olivier, i must admit that i didn't know that this flag exist. I should better read the documentation [here](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection). But, i have to prevent users that file already exist (with popup) so i think, i must still use a check function.  Thanks

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thank you, i will check the post

Comment: The best flag to use is for my project : confirmoverwrite :)

Comment: So consider posting it as an answer.